# Rspec let variable producing weird result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am having a weird issue with RSpec that I don't quite understand.

This is my `port_stock_spec.rb` file:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: port_stocks
#
#  id                :bigint(8)        not null, primary key
#  portfolio_id      :integer
#  stock_id          :integer
#  volume            :integer
#  transaction_price :float
#  current_price     :float
#  percent_change    :float
#  created_at        :datetime         not null
#  updated_at        :datetime         not null
#  current_value     :float
#  dollar_change     :float
#  total_spend       :float
#  transaction_date  :datetime
#  action            :integer
#  position          :integer          default("open")
#  ticker            :string
#  slug              :string
#

require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe PortStock, type: :model do
  let(:stock) { create(:stock, price: 10.00) }
  let(:portfolio) { create(:portfolio) }
  let(:port_stock_1) { create(:port_stock, stock: stock, portfolio: portfolio, transaction_price: stock.price, action: :buy, volume: 100) }

  context "associations" do
    it { should belong_to(:portfolio) }
    it { should belong_to (:stock) }
  end

  context "methods" do
    it "should accurately calculate the positive percent_change of the current PortStock" do
      port_stock_1.current_price = 20.00
      expect(port_stock_1.calculate_percent_change).to eql 100.00
    end

    it "should accurately calculate the negative percent_change of the current PortStock" do
      port_stock_1.current_price = 5.00
      expect(port_stock_1.calculate_percent_change).to eql(-50.00)
    end

    it "should accurately calculate the negative dollar_change of the current PortStock" do
      port_stock_1.current_price = 5.00
      port_stock_1.volume = 1000
      expect(port_stock_1.calculate_dollar_change).to eql (-5000.00)
    end

    # more specs that may or may no interact with the let variables.            

    it "should accurately calculate the portfolio's initial_dollar_value" do
      expect(portfolio.initial_dollar_value).to eql 1000.00
    end
```

end

Then I have the following method on my `portfolio.rb` model:

```
  def calculate_portfolio_initial_dollar_value
    if self.portfolio.initial_dollar_value.nil?
      self.portfolio.initial_dollar_value = 0.0
    end
    self.portfolio.initial_dollar_value += (self.transaction_price * self.volume)
    self.portfolio.save!
  end
```

When I run my test suite, that last test keeps failing, when it shouldn't:

```
Failures:

  1) PortStock methods should accurately calculate the portfolio's initial_dollar_value
     Failure/Error: expect(portfolio.initial_dollar_value).to eql 1000.00

       expected: 1000.0
            got: 798229.0

       (compared using eql?)
     # ./spec/models/port_stock_spec.rb:77:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 5.05 seconds (files took 3.68 seconds to load)
29 examples, 1 failure, 19 pending
```

So I put a `binding.pry` within the `it` blocks of the last few tests and when I check the `portfolio.initial_dollar_value` it repeatedly changes the value.

```
[1] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::PortStock::Methods>)> portfolio
=> #<Portfolio:0x00007fcdc5c5db28
 id: 14,
 user_id: 7,
 current_dollar_value: 2864770.0,
 percent_change: 75.02,
 created_at: Sat, 13 Apr 2019 00:36:24 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Sat, 13 Apr 2019 00:36:24 UTC +00:00,
 num_winners: 2,
 num_losers: 7,
 initial_dollar_value: 860679.0,
 dollar_change: 92865.0>
[2] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::PortStock::Methods>)> port_stock_1.portfolio
=> #<Portfolio:0x00007fcdc5c5db28
 id: 14,
 user_id: 7,
 current_dollar_value: 150.0,
 percent_change: -85.0,
 created_at: Sat, 13 Apr 2019 00:36:24 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Sat, 13 Apr 2019 00:36:42 UTC +00:00,
 num_winners: 0,
 num_losers: 1,
 initial_dollar_value: 1000.0,
 dollar_change: -850.0>
[3] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::PortStock::Methods>)> portfolio
=> #<Portfolio:0x00007fcdc5c5db28
 id: 14,
 user_id: 7,
 current_dollar_value: 150.0,
 percent_change: -85.0,
 created_at: Sat, 13 Apr 2019 00:36:24 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Sat, 13 Apr 2019 00:36:42 UTC +00:00,
 num_winners: 0,
 num_losers: 1,
 initial_dollar_value: 1000.0,
 dollar_change: -850.0>
[4] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::PortStock::Methods>)> portfolio
=> #<Portfolio:0x00007fcdc5c5db28
 id: 14,
 user_id: 7,
 current_dollar_value: 150.0,
 percent_change: -85.0,
 created_at: Sat, 13 Apr 2019 00:36:24 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Sat, 13 Apr 2019 00:36:42 UTC +00:00,
 num_winners: 0,
 num_losers: 1,
 initial_dollar_value: 1000.0,
 dollar_change: -850.0>
[5] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::PortStock::Methods>)>
```

I don't understand why.

Thoughts?

**Edit 1**

This is `portfolio.rb` Factory:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :portfolio do
    user
    current_dollar_value { Faker::Number.number(7) }
    percent_change { Faker::Number.decimal(2) }
    num_winners { Faker::Number.number(1) }
    num_losers { Faker::Number.number(1) }
    initial_dollar_value { Faker::Number.number(6) }
    dollar_change { Faker::Number.number(5) }
  end
end
```

**Edit 2**

There is a callback on my `port_stock.rb` model that triggers methods related to `portfolio_initial_dollar_value`:

```
after_save :calculate_portfolio_initial_dollar_value
```

Also other callbacks that impact other aspects of the portfolio:

```
  after_save :update_portfolio_current_dollar_value
  after_save :update_portfolio_initial_dollar_value, if: (:total_spend_previously_changed? || :volume_previously_changed?)

  def update_portfolio_current_dollar_value
    self.portfolio.current_dollar_value = self.portfolio.port_stocks.open.map(&:current_value).sum
    self.portfolio.save!
  end

  def update_portfolio_initial_dollar_value
    self.portfolio.initial_dollar_value = self.portfolio.port_stocks.open.map { |ps| ps.volume * ps.transaction_price }.sum
    self.portfolio.save!
  end
```

**Edit 3**

For the full version both the model (`port_stock.rb`) & spec (`port_stock_spec.rb`) files, check [out this gist](https://gist.github.com/marcamillion/1cc97184e33a1cc65de2b5c622f79164). I didn't want to pollute SO with that full dump.

Comment: Are these order-dependent tests?

Comment: @tadman No...they aren't.

Comment: Could you provide the code of `port_stock` model and `portfolio` model and factory?

Comment: @AlexanderRyhlitsky The `port_stock` model is too complicated and I don't want to pollute the question too much. But I added the `portfolio` factory.

Comment: @marcamillion  I was thinking that inside any of model there could be some sort of callback that changes `portfolio` model. Is there something similar?

Comment: Second pry shows different `updated_at`. Obviously, you have to search for _your_ code (not Rspec), where `portfolio` is updated.

Comment: Also, based on the Failure title, you didn't provide source of failed spec. It could show us an order of models creation.

Comment: Is there a callback that triggers the `calculate_portfolio_initial_dollar_value` method? Could you please share how or when that method is called?

Comment: @AnujKhandelwal I updated the question to show that callback and a few others.

Comment: @AlexanderRyhlitsky you are correct, there are a lot of callbacks. I didn't want to paste the entire model here, but I have made a gist of it here - https://gist.github.com/marcamillion/1cc97184e33a1cc65de2b5c622f79164. That gist also includes the full spec file.

Comment: @PavelMikhailyuk please see the full files for both the `port_stock.rb` model and the associated spec file at this gist - https://gist.github.com/marcamillion/1cc97184e33a1cc65de2b5c622f79164

Comment: @marcamillion did you find any of the answers helpful? If so, please mark it as accepted.
Please let us know, if you miss something or anything is unclear.

Answer (score 4):

As @grzekos point out you never call `stock` or `port_stock_1` during the execution of `it "should accurately calculate the portfolio's initial_dollar_value"` test.

Why? Because you used `let` to setup/create the test objects.
If you want to always setup/create `stock`, `portfolio` and `port_stock_1` you can either use `let!` ([RSpec documentation](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-8/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let#use-%60let!%60-to-define-a-memoized-helper-method-that-is-called-in-a-%60before%60-hook)) or use a `before` block like this:

```
let(:stock) { create(:stock, price: 10.00) }
let(:portfolio) { create(:portfolio) }
let(:port_stock_1) { create(:port_stock, stock: stock, portfolio: portfolio, transaction_price: stock.price, action: :buy, volume: 100) }

before do
  stock
  portfolio
  port_stock_1
end
```

Why do you see different numbers during debuging with `pry`?

In your first test you called the `portfolio` object, which was created with FactoryBot. The Factory asinged a random 6 digit number to the `initial_dollar_value` atttribute via `Faker::Number.number(6)`.

In your second test you called `port_stock_1.portfolio`. Now the block of `let(:port_stock_1)` gets evaluated. This creates a `PortStock` object, which in its `after_save` method updates the `initial_dollar_value` of `portfolio`.

All subsequet calls of `portfolio` or `port_stock_1.portfolio` do not change the value of `initial_dollar_value` anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so the failing test is:

```
    it "should accurately calculate the portfolio's initial_dollar_value" do
      expect(portfolio.initial_dollar_value).to eql 1000.00
    end
```

Here I can see that you create the `portfolio` object and the `initial_dollar_value` is set (in the factory) to `Faker::Number.number(6)`. Why do you expect it to be equal to 1000.00?

The `stock` or the `port_stock_1` objects are never created when you run this particular test. Quoting the [Rspec let documentation](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let)

> Use let to define a memoized helper method. The value will be cached across
>   multiple calls in the same example **but not across examples**.
>   Note that let is lazy-evaluated: it is not evaluated until the first time
>   the method it defines is invoked.